# When converted, why does an EPOCH time return a date 1 min 15s earlier than expected

Tags: date, timezone, epoch

I have an epoch date: -4361126400 (a date in the 1830s).
When I use https://www.epochconverter.com/, I get the following result (I get the same result with other online converters also):

GMT: Friday, October 21, 1831 12:00:00 AM

Your time zone: Thursday, October 20, 1831 11:58:45 PM GMT+00:00

If I try another date such as -13482000 (a day in 1969) the result is fine showing the full hour offset for my timezone as expected.
Another date in the 1810s  (-5031071925) on the other hand has a 1 min 15s offset.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: https://codeofmatt.com/please-dont-call-it-epoch-time/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re probably in Europe/London time zone. The UK changed their time in 1847. Before that time the clocks were 1 minute 15 seconds earlier. From 1847 (and uninterrupted until 1916, when summer time (DST) was introduced), they were on GMT (Greenwich Mean Time).

One way to see this is on *Time Zone in London, England, United Kingdom* on timeanddate.com, see the link at the bottom and choose 1800 – 1849 in the *Time zone changes for* dropdown. For the time up to 1846 it says:

> No changes, UTC -0:01:15 hours all of the period

Then it announces the change in 1847:

> 1847  ons 1. dec, kl. 00.00   LMT → GMT   +0:01:15 hours (TZ change)  UTC

(sorry, my Firefox talks Danish).

When *Epoch & Unix Timestamp Conversion Tools* that you used shows 11:58:45 PM, the offset is 1 minut 15 seconds. So this is what you get in the 1810s and in the 1830s. When it displays your time zone as “GMT+00:00”, it’s really misleading because it has correctly applied “GMT-00:01:15” for the time displayed. It seems that they just display today’s offset (I haven’t investigated further, you may yourself, of course).

**Links:**

- [Time Zone in London, England, United Kingdom](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london)
- Related question: [Intl.DateTimeFormat gives strange result from year 1847 or below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512717/intl-datetimeformat-gives-strange-result-from-year-1847-or-below)

Comment: Thanks Ole V.V., much appreciated. This explains all. I have corrected by poor methematics in the title also. Thanks again. C